# System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown when using Tcp Sockets

Tags: c#, sockets

I am working for remoting service with Iphone using Tcp protocol Socket programming for window Application. We used  `int BufferSize = 999900000.`

When one to one client connected to each other for chat, it is working fine. But after sending about 35 messages I am getting error:

> "Client added function call catch blockException of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown."

How can we resolve this issue?

It's a critical error because the exe did not send any response due to this kind of error.

Comment: While we could probably guess, it might be better if you could show more code than just how you declared an int variable.

Comment: are you free-ing your un-managed resources?

Answer (score 5):

It appears you're allocating an **900MB+** buffer to send and/or receive data. It is not out of the question that you would run out of memory at some point with an allocation strategy such as that.

Comment: Exactly, why do you need such a huge buffer?